# Can we use IN () AND NOT IN () with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want my SQL request to take some rows but skip another ones using a IN () AND NOT IN ().
But this doesn't seem to work properly. Do anybody have an idea why ?

Thanks !

```
SELECT *
FROM   `prospect`
WHERE  id IN (SELECT idprospect
              FROM   envoi_prospect
              WHERE  idenvoi IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4',
                                  '6', '7', '10', '12' )
       AND id NOT IN (SELECT idprospect
                      FROM   envoi_prospect
                      WHERE  idenvoi IN ( '8', '9', '11', '13' ))
ORDER  BY `date` DESC
LIMIT  0, 30
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes. "This doesn't work properly" is not a valid error message or bad behaviour informartion though.

Comment: Try setting up an example in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/). This way you can give us a sample of data to see what your trying to do and better help.

Answer (score 2):

While the SQL syntax certainly allows it, it does not really make sense to apply an IN filter and a NOT IN filter at the same time.

Consider a table containing the following records:

```
ColA
1
2
3
4
```

If you write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE
    ColA IN (1, 2) AND
    ColA NOT IN (4)
```

The output will be:

```
ColA
1
2
```

The IN statement filters your query to only include the rows where ColA is 1 or 2. Thus, in this case, the NOT IN query is completely unnecessary. Now, if you write a query like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE
    ColA IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    ColA NOT IN (3, 4)
```

The output will be the same as above. Why? Well, since you have an `AND` operator between the IN and the NOT IN statements, both must evaluate to TRUE, for a record to be outputtet. Now, for the 3rd row in the table, `ColA IN (1, 2, 3)` evaluates to TRUE, but `ColA NOT IN (3, 4)` evaluates to FALSE, and thus the 3rd row is not outputted.

Comment: +1 for the explaination, but the "solution" to his problem was the bracket problem as Pankaj Jawale noticed.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thanks - didn't notice that. Leaving the answer as it is, as someone else might find it useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You miss placed the Brackets thats it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `prospect`
WHERE  id IN (SELECT idprospect
              FROM   envoi_prospect
              WHERE  idenvoi IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4',
                                  '6', '7', '10', '12' ))
       AND id NOT IN (SELECT idprospect
                      FROM   envoi_prospect
                      WHERE  idenvoi IN ( '8', '9', '11', '13' ))
ORDER  BY `date` DESC
LIMIT  0, 30
```

You can rewrite the query as  :

```
    SELECT *
        FROM   `prospect`
        WHERE  id IN (SELECT idprospect
                      FROM   envoi_prospect
                      WHERE  idenvoi IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4',
                                          '6', '7', '10', '12' ) And
                             idenvoi NOT IN ( '8', '9', '11', '13' ) )
    ORDER  BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT  0, 30
```

Comment: Note that the `NOT IN` condition is not necessary. If `id` is in some `idenvoi`, it can't be also in others...

Comment: The `NOT IN` is not redundant here. It would only be redundant if the subqueries did `SELECT idenvoi` instead of `SELECT idprospect`, but in this case, it's entirely possible that the `NOT IN` part really does filter out results.

Comment: @hvd can you explain, how NOT IN part really does filter out results.

Comment: @PankajJawale What you have in your answer now, the second bit, means `NOT IN` has no benefits. But for the first bit (only changing the parentheses, leaving the query as is otherwise), suppose you have (idprospect, idenvoi) values of (1, 1) and (1, 8). The prospect with ID 1 should be filtered out, and with the first query in your answer, is filtered out. The second query will incorrectly keep that prospect in the results.